# How to display a unique header image to blog category and subcategory in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, conditional-statements, categories

I am using the following code to display a specific header graphic depending on what page or category the viewer is on:

```
<!-- Custom Design masthead -->
<?php if ( is_page(259) ) { ?>
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/masthead-1.jpg" width="1140" height="250" alt="Custom Acrylic Furniture" />

<!-- About and sub-pages masthead -->
<?php } elseif ( is_page(array(245,348,352,357,325)) ) { ?>
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/masthead-2.jpg" width="1140" height="250" alt="Custom Acrylic Furniture" />

<!-- Design Community masthead -->
<?php } elseif ( is_page(array(365,568)) ) { ?>
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/masthead-3.jpg" width="1140" height="250" alt="Custom Acrylic Furniture" />

<!-- Contact and Privacy masthead -->
<?php } elseif ( is_page(array(264,330)) ) { ?>
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/masthead-4.jpg" width="1140" height="250" alt="Custom Acrylic Furniture" />

<!-- Blog masthead -->
<?php } elseif ( is_category(4) ) { ?>
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/masthead-5.jpg" width="1140" height="250" alt="Custom Acrylic Furniture" />

<?php } else { ?>
<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/masthead-0.jpg" width="1140" height="250" alt="Custom Acrylic Furniture" />

<?php }?>
```

So far, so good. The problem I am running into is how to modify the following statement:

```
<!-- Blog masthead -->
<?php } elseif ( is_category(4) ) { ?>
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/masthead-5.jpg" width="1140" height="250" alt="Custom Acrylic Furniture" />
```

so that it includes the category and any subcategories.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the subcategories of current category like
$this_cat = (get_query_var('cat')) ? get_query_var('cat') : 1; 
 wp_list_categories('child_of=' . $this_cat . '');

After that you need to apply the conditions.